# Order a "sub level" record - ORM

Tags: oop, orm

Let's say we use an ORM like Doctrine and Symfony2 as Framework.

Whe have three entity (A,B,C) related eache other in that fashion:

```
A --[1-m]-- B
B --[m-1]-- C
```

Let's now say that `C` has an attribute (table column) that tell us the correct order of `C` records (for user display purposes). 
Finally, we have an object of `A` type fetched using ORM.

What's the best approach - if any - for return `C` object ordered starting from `A` ? Have I to write a custom query and, so, lose ORM characteristics?

#### Notice

If you don't get the problem, let's remember that, for retrieve `C` object, you have to pass through `B` objects which could be ordered in different way as order field is onto `C` object and, of course, "copy" order also onto `B` object isn't a good solution

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT a, b, c
FROM Mapping:EntityA a
JOIN a.b b
JOIN b.c c
ORDER BY b.prop1 ASC, c.prop1 ASC
```

That's all there is to it really. All `c's` that belong to a `b` are ordered, while all `b's` belonging to an `a` are ordered as well.

Comment: First of all, thank you but I perfectly know how to make a query (and, as I mention above, I want to know if there is an alternative method by using Objects and I suppose answer is no). However, your query isn't such good: B haven't (and I don't want to add) a column or property for do an order by.

Comment: There is an alternative method with using Objects, but databases are so much faster when doing operations like this. So this is preferred. So make your question more constructive, or accept this and open a new question if you will, and explain the particular use case.